# C : compare two character arrays

Tags: c, pointers

C : compare two character arrays

Here's my rot function

```
int my_rot13(int c) {
    if ('a' <= tolower(c) && tolower(c) <= 'z')
        return tolower(c)+13 <= 'z' ? c+13 : c-13;
    return c;
}

int my_rot13cmp(char *a, char *b) {
    int i;
    for (i=1; i<strlen(a); i++) {
        if (my_rot13(a[i]) > my_rot13(b[i])) {
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

And this should output 1 because 
D will be Q in decoded character
W will be J in decoded character
And Q > J

```
printf("%d \n", my_rot13cmp("\0D\n", "\0W\n"));
```

But this keeps giving me -1

What is the correct way to compare these two characters?

Comment: `for (i=1; i<strlen(a); i++)` -- this is about the worst way possible to iterate over a string. Learn about the idiomatic `while(*p++)`.

Comment: @Jon, weeeelllllll ... I have an easier time understanding the way it was written than `while(*p++)`.  "Less elegant" isn't always worse.  "Easy to read" trumps elegance a lot of the time, in my experience.

Comment: @John: I agree, but `strlen` in the condition is a common example of what *not* to do. I 'm all for clarity when reading, but at least move the `strlen` outside. Incidentally, it's a good idea to think about why people do not realize this is wrong: because they don't realize that `strlen` is internally a `while(*p++)`...   ;-)

Comment: @Jon, ha ... count me among those who didn't realize it, but it does make perfect sense.  You're right.  Doing it that way turns it from O(n) into an O(n^2) problem.  All I was really commenting on was that `while(*p++)` is a bit arcane to the uninitiated.  But thanks for making the inefficiency explicit.  I learned something new today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strlen looks for `\0` symbol to determine string length, your strings has this special symbol, so strlen will not work, you have several variants:

**1** have separate argument for length, like:

```
int my_rot13cmp(char *a, char *b, size_t aLength, size_t bLength)
{
    if (aLength > bLength)
        return 1;
    if (aLength < bLength)
        return -1;
    for (int i=0; i<aLength; i++)
        if (my_rot13(a[i]) > my_rot13(b[i]))
            return 1;
        else if (my_rot13(a[i]) < my_rot13(b[i]))
            return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

**2** if you know that all your strings just started with `\0` and do not contain it until the end (asciiz null terminator must be), you can go with this solution:

```
int my_rot13cmp(char *a, char *b)
{
    a++; b++; // skips first \0 symbol
    for (int i=0; i<strlen(a); i++) // note: what will be if A is longer than B?
        if (my_rot13(a[i]) > my_rot13(b[i]))
            return 1;
        else if (my_rot13(a[i]) < my_rot13(b[i]))
            return -1;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You have an embedded 0 character in your strings:

```
 my_rot13cmp("\0D\n", "\0W\n");
```

This will cause `strlen(a)` inside my_rot13cmp to return 0 - since a nul character means the end of the string.

Remove those \0 in your strings, and start the loop at `i=0`